# Constant Score Query elasticsearch boosting

Tags: elasticsearch, information-retrieval

My understanding of Constant Score Query in elasticsearch is that boost factor would be assigned as score for every matching query. The [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html) says:

> A query that wraps a filter or another query and simply returns a constant score equal to the query boost for every document in the filter.

However when I send this query:

```
"query": {
    "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
            "term": {
                "source": "BBC"
            }
        },
        "boost": 3
    }
},
"fields": ["title", "source"]
```

all the matching documents are given a score of 1?! I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong, and had also tried with query instead of filter in constant_score.

Comment: run the same query with [explain](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html#search-request-explain) set to true and probably will get a better insight into the score.

Answer (score 3):

Scores are only meant to be relative to all other scores in a given result set, so a result set where everything has the score of 3 is the same as a result set where everything has the score of 1.

> Really, the only purpose of the relevance _score is to sort the results of the current query in the correct order. You should not try to compare the relevance scores from different queries. - [Elasticsearch Guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html#query-norm)

Either the constant score is being ignored because it's not being combined with another query or it's being normalized. As @keety said, check to the output of [explain](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html) to see exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

`Constant score query` gives equal score to any matching document irrespective any scoring factors like TF, IDF etc. This can be used when you don't care whether how much a doc matched but just if a doc matched or not and give a score too, unlike `filter`.

If you want score as 3 literally for all the matching documents for a particular query, then you should be using [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html), something like

```json
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "functions": [
            {
                "filter": { "term": { "source": "BBC" } },
                "weight": 3
            }
        ]
    }
    ...
}
```